# Import-Csv and Export-Csv with same name and path

Tags: powershell, csv

This should be a fairly simple question to answer, but I haven't been able to find a resource online. I need to remove rows from a `csv` with out changing the filename or path. Currently I am trying to import the file, filter the items I need and export that data to the same location with the same file name:

```
foreach ($csv in $csvLists){
Import-Csv $csv | Where-Object {[DateTime]$_.'Date' -ge $2WeeksOld} | Export-Csv $csv -NoType -Force
}
```

Also tried:

```
foreach ($csv in $csvLists){
Import-Csv $csv | Where-Object {[DateTime]$_.'Date' -ge $2WeeksOld} | Export-Csv $csv.PSParentPath -NoType -Force
}
```

I am getting access denied errors:

```
Export-Csv : Access to the path 'D:\Test' is denied.
At C:\script.ps1:20 char:71
+ ... .'Date' -ge $2WeeksOld} | Export-Csv $csv.PSParentPath -NoType -Force
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

What am I missing here? Is the issue that powershell is reading the file and cant export over it at the same time? Should I try setting the imported data as a variable and then exporting the csv outside the `import-csv` pipeline?

As always thanks for any help.

Comment: Any chance that you happen to be viewing the file in an app?

Comment: Nevermind, the error looks like you are being denied access to the folder. Do you have write permissions for that folder?

Comment: Why `$csv.PSParentPath`? Does using `$csv.Fullname` instead resolve the issue?

Comment: @gms0ulman I was under the impression $csv would contain the file name and PSParentPath would provide the path, not sure why I didn't just use Fullname to begin with! This works, please provide your response as an answer and I will confirm it. Do you have more information on how to properly use PSParentPath? I think I may be using it wrong.

Comment: `$csv.PSParentPath` does contain the directory of a `FileInfo` object, but most people would use `$csv.DirectoryName` or `$csv.Directory.FullName`.  However if `$Csv` is `C:\Test\File.csv`, then `Export-Csv -Path $Csv.PSParentPath` is going to try to create a file in `C:\ ` called `Test`.  That's not going to work.  NTFS won't allow objects with the same name in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$csv.FullName`. This contains the full path for a file/folder.
Here are a few common properties of `System.IO.FileInfo`:

```
Property        Contents
BaseName        MyFile
Directory*      <returns System.IO.DirectoryInfo object of "C:\Path\To">
Name            MyFile.txt
FullName        C:\Path\To\MyFile.txt
PSParentPath    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Path\To
```

I'm not aware of a use case for `.PSParentPath`. Looking at the content, I assume it's used when you need to specify the [PSProvider](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=729101&seqNum=3) as well as the string value of the parent. Otherwise you could just use `.Directory.Name`

You may find the class definitions for [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) useful. They are the objects returned by `Get-ChildItem`. The links list Methods and Properties; they do not list Code/Note/ScriptProperty types.

**tip:** run `$csv | Get-Member` to see members of this object, look at `MemberType`.

<sub>* For System.IO.DirectoryInfo objects, use Parent. Have got some different behaviour in Win10 and am sure an alias was instroduced so that Parent works for FileInfo or Directory works for DirectoryInfo.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you're trying to do everything in one line, and consequently you're opening a file (which locks it) and trying to overwrite the same file (which needs to lock it) at the same time.  That won't work.

Try:

```
foreach ($csv in $csvLists){
    $Data = Import-Csv $csv | Where-Object {[DateTime]$_.'Date' -ge $2WeeksOld}
    $Data | Export-Csv $csv -NoType -Force
}
```

Or, if `$csvLists` is an array of `FileInfo` objects (such as from the output of `Get-ChildItem`):

```
foreach ($csv in $csvLists){
    $Data = Import-Csv $csv.FullName | Where-Object {[DateTime]$_.'Date' -ge $2WeeksOld}
    $Data | Export-Csv $csv.FullName -NoType -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is basically what I was suggesting in the last bit of my question. This works, although it adds an additional variable and line. I think the response from @gms0ulman will work better for me in this instance.