# Why is Export-CSV overwriting the entire CSV contents instead of just specified data?

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

Part2List.csv:

```
Name,Date,Location
ADMRYANTEST1, 08/03/2018, 1
ADMRYANTEST2, 09/03/2018, 1
```

PowerShell command:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Date -gt (Get-Date)} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

(Get-Date) is today: August 3, 2018. The command should only erase `ADMRYANTEST1`.

**Why is my entire file being erased?**

Comment: To me it is not clear if the $_.date holds `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`. Try  `[datetime]::ParseExact()` before the compare

Comment: @Theo It is mm/dd/yyyy. Not sure if this is what you meant - but I tried  `Where-Object {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date) -gt (Get-Date)}` and it didn't fix it.

Comment: Did you get the answer you needed? If so, please accept the appropriate one; otherwise, please provide feedback. I've noticed that you've only accepted answer to 3 out of your 12 questions so far, so I encourage you to revisit your old questions too to see if answers should be accepted there.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is my entire file being erased?

**Because you cannot read from and write back to the *same file* in the same pipeline**, UNLESS you make sure that the input file is read into memory, in full, *before* its lines are sent through the pipeline.

To that end, **enclose the command that reads the input file in parentheses (`(...)`)**, which ensures that it is run to completion, with all output collected in memory and the input file closed again, *before* pipeline processing starts:

```
(Import-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List.csv") | # !! Note the (...)
  ... | 
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that this approach bears a **slight risk of data loss**, if the pipeline is interrupted before writing all data back to the input file has completed.

A **more robust approach is to write to a temporary file first**, and, on successful completion (only), replace the original file.

With either approach, if the original file had special permissions, alternate data streams, ..., you may want to recreate these too.

---

As pointed out in [Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51680428/45375), **you have an *additional problem***: **CSV column values are always imported as *strings***, so you must **perform explicit conversions as needed**:

Since you're doing a date comparison, you must convert `$_.Date` to a `[datetime]` instance; since your input is in format `MM/dd/yyyy`, which is the invariant culture's<sup>[1]</sup>
 short date pattern, you can simply *cast* to `[datetime]`.

```
(Import-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List.csv") | 
  Where-Object { [datetime] $_.Date -gt (Get-Date) } | 
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell uses the *invariant culture* (`[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`) rather than the *current culture* for to-and-from string conversions in most contexts. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

After importing the CSV, $_.Date holds a string, not a DateTime object. Later, you try and compare this string to the current date (= object).
Because the format is 'MM/dd/yyyy' as you say, you should do something like this to have Powershell be able to compare this as DateTime object.
That is where the `DateTime]::ParseExact()` function comes in:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List.csv" | Where-Object {([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)) -gt (Get-Date)} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List_Output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Also, if no date greater than today is found in the CSV the output will be empty.. (can there be future dates in the csv at all?)

Note that i have changed the name of the output so you don't overwrite the original csv file

Comment: You are right, neverthless you should enclose the Import-Csv in parentheses to get the content into memory before writing to the same file name.

Comment: True, but my code saves to a new file, not the same file that is being read in. That would indeed need the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Can't have the command in 1 line beacuse the file is locked when it is opened per https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326987/6402199.

This fixes it!

```
$new = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Date -gt (Get-Date)}
$new | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Part2List.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You can also put the `Import-Csv` part in parentheses to ensure it's fully executed before passing the results down the pipeline.

Comment: No it doesn't. It just happens that the  string from the csv compares greater than Get-Date cast to a string.